# What is the origin country of the bicycle brand called Longhorn?

Tags: road-bike

I recently brought a hybrid bicycle from a brand called **Longhorn**. I have never heard about it. However the quality is quite good. So I am quite curious to know from which country the brand originates and if it has been established for a long time or if it is a newer brand. I brought the bike from India.

Comment: A very quick Google search suggests it's an Indian brand. The actual manufacturing may be outsourced or not.

Comment: There's heaps of useful results if you try a search engine like google.  "longhorn bicycle" returns mostly Indian results, with one exception being a shop in Austin, Texas.

Comment: I had a quick google myself, and the answer certainly didn't leap out at me.  Seems to me like a valid question where the answer is not easy to find.  We certainly happily provide answers on other things that are much easier to google

Comment: I posted the question. I did a google search myself but the answers were too vague thats why I posted it here. Heck I dont even know the well known brands outside India. There are so many of them.

Comment: I'd ask the other way round: can you find any reference to Longhorn branded bikes outside India? BSO brands are usually seller specific, so the exact same bike would be branded Roadmaster or Kent at Walmart and Yosemite at our local equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can find and answer in this article:
https://www.tribuneindia.com/news/archive/features/indian-bicycle-industry-losing-sheen-336950

> In fact, a couple of firms here have started manufacturing bicycles abroad. Suneet Syal from Vinsun Enterprises said they were manufacturing bicycles by the name of Longhorn and Chase in China and importing these here*.

*India